# Initiate Outgoing Call to an Automated System - Twilio

Tags: twilio

I'm writing a Twilio function to make an outgoing call to a company's automatic phone system. From there I want to record and transcribe the conversation. However, I'm having trouble understanding how to start the call. Do I need to write an additional script to start the Twilio function? Or is there something more obvious I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can execute the Twilio Function via the URL/Path you created. You can also use other Twilio products, like Studio, to execute the Function.

You could use [Twilio Studio](https://www.twilio.com/studio) to do everything you are attempting to do without a Function, by using the [REST API trigger](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007778153-Trigger-a-Twilio-Studio-Flow-Execution-via-the-REST-API) and [Make Outgoing Call Widget](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/make-outgoing-call), and one of the transcription options described here, [Transcribe entire phone calls with Twilio](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223133027-Transcribe-entire-phone-calls-with-Twilio), say for example [Voicebase High Accuracy Transcription](https://showcase.twilio.com/s/partner-listing/a8E1W00000097RMUAY/voicebase-high-accuracy-transcription).

Comment: I didn't know about Twilio Studio, I'll definitely check that out! What do you mean via the URL/Path? I know we can specify a URL in our Twilio calls, but I'm not understanding what I should be doing. Do I need to visit that URL every time I want to make an outgoing call? I'm new to web programming so if these seem like basic questions they probably are. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: From what I understand, the URL is used to add additional instructions for Twilio while on the call. However, the only things I want to do are listed in the create() parameters (record, transcribe, sendDigits, to, from). Is a URL still necessary? Thanks for any direction you can give me.